# Probability of being same birthday of at least three people

Tags: probability

What is the probability that in a randomly chosen group of r people at least three people have the same birthday?

I have tried doing this question as fallows- 1-(probability of all people having different birthday+ any 2 people have same birthday+2 people in each of 2 sets have same birthdays but distinct for particular set+probability of 2 people in each of 3 sets have same birthdays but distinct for particular set+.......)

but i can't generalize it....

Comment: I have tried doing this question as fallows-

Comment: 1-(probability of all people having different birthday+ any 2 people have same birthday+2 sets of 2 people each have distinct same birthdays+.......)

Comment: but i am unable to generalize its result.

Comment: You should add what you tried to the question. Don't put it in comments.

Comment: @MayankChaturvedi please take a look at my solution. Hope this helps you understand the question.