# How to pair up even number of people sitting around a circle, when opposites cannot be paired?

Tags: combinatorics

If 2n people are sitting at equally spaced intervals around a circle. How many ways can they form n pairs if no two persons seated directly opposite each other can form a pair?

What I did was draw some examples for low values of 'n' and also tried to see it as a graph on 2n vertices where there is no edge between opposite vertices. However, I have not come to a revelation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: got it... Thank you. :-)

Comment: Could you show what your results were for the values of $n$ that you tried?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

$2n$ persons can form $\binom{2n}{2}$ pairs without restrictions.

How many pairs must we subtract from that due to the restriction ?

---

I am assuming that the $2n$ persons have already been seated in some order.

Then each of $n$ persons will have a specific person opposite with whom they can't form a pair,

thus $\binom{2n}{2} - n$ allowable pairs.

Comment: two people can form one pair without restriction.

Comment: And if they are arranged evenly on a circle, they can't form a pair at all due to the restriction.

Comment: I was only showing that the statement that "$2n$ persons can form $\binom{2n}{n}$ pairs without restrictions" is not correct.

Comment: Oh, corrected the stupid typo, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As shown at the beginning of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1574666), without restriction, there are $(2n-1)!!$ ways to form pairs with $2n$ people.  Let us count how many ways there are to pair at least one opposite using Inclusion-Exclusion.

There are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose $k$ opposites. For each of those choices, there are $(2n-2k-1)!!$ ways to form pairs with the $2n-2k$ left. Inclusion-Exclusion says that there are
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}(2n-2k-1)!!
$$
pairings with at least one pair of opposites. Subtracting this from $(2n-1)!!$ gives
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(2n-2k-1)!!}
$$
ways to pair without matching opposites.
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\\hline
\text{pairings}&0&2&8&60&544&6040&79008&1190672&20314880
\end{array}
$$
Here are the $8$ pairings for $n=3$:

[image]

Comment: What is your interpretation of the question ? Initially I though *derangements*, but "$2n$ people are sitting in a circle.." would seem to indicate that we need to work out pairings for any *particular* seating

Comment: @trueblueanil: I have added an image for $n=3$ which gives $8$ pairings.

Comment: I  understand your interpretation, you are simultaneously pairing all the people sitting in a circle, while I interpreted it as the sides and chords of a polygon excluding chords that pass through the center.

Comment: The question asks "How many ways can they form $n$ pairs if no two persons seated directly opposite each other can form a pair?" Each of the $8$ arrangements in the $n=3$ image above is "a way to form $3$ pairs if no two persons seated directly opposite each other can form a pair."

Comment: I just noticed that the Wikipedia page for [Double Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) has an [image for all pairings of $6$ points](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/Chord_diagrams_K6_matchings.svg/720px-Chord_diagrams_K6_matchings.svg.png).

Comment: Your answer is right for your interpretation. (+1) See https://oeis.org/A053871/internal

Comment: @trueblueanil: thanks for the link. That offers some interesting alternate interpretations of the same sequence.

Comment: Regarding my interpretation: the question asks "how many ways can they form $n$ pairs", not "how many pairs can be formed".

Comment: I agree with your interpretation, yeah OEIS always gives so many ideas !